# Show Disabled Entries

Tags: entries

I have a page on one of my sites which requires entries to show even if the entry is disabled, but just greyed out. Is there a way I can disable an entry and make it still show up on my webpage?

I have tried using {% if not entry.enabled %} but it doesn't show up either way. Also I'd rather it showed up in the order its laid out in the admin, not before or after.

The field I am trying to display is an entries field which is taking data from another Structure and is disabled in that Structure, not the one which it is being called into.

Anyway of doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a `status(null)` to the `ElementCriteriaModel` to search for disabled entries.

```
{% set enties = craft.entries.status(null).find() %}
```

If you have a `RelationField` you would just add it before you fetch the entries

```
{% set relatedEntries = entry.myAwesomeField.status(null).find() %}
```